# Is account linking enough to publish an action on google that does financial transactions?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, account-linking

I want to build an Actions on Google app which can transfer money/purchase products etc. Is account linking enough for this app to get approved by Google or do I need to use Transactions API. Also, is there a limited list of countries where Transactions API works? There used to be a list of countries where it worked. This app is supposed to target India

Answer (score 1):

According to the [platform policies](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/policies/general-policies#special_requirements_for_certain_use_cases):

> If your Action enables users to complete a physical goods or services transaction, or make a reservation or booking, it must implement the Transactions API for Assistant. This does not include adding items to a basket.
>
> If your Actions enables users to complete a digital transaction or buy a subscription, it must implement the Digital Purchase API.

Additionally:

> Peer to peer transfers are not permitted, unless using App Actions. Actions that provide bank account information, such as credit balances, must implement account linking.

The list of available countries is [available in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-custom), which does not include India.